# How do I overcome match arms with incompatible types for structs implementing same trait?

Tags: rust

I am attempting to write the `cat` command to learn Rust, but I can't seem to convert command line arguments into reader structs.

```
use std::{env, io};
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    for arg in env::args().skip(1) {
        let reader = match arg.as_str() {
            "-" => io::stdin(),
            path => File::open(&path).unwrap(),
        };
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0308]: match arms have incompatible types
 --> src/main.rs:6:22
  |
6 |         let reader = match arg.as_str() {
  |                      ^ expected struct `std::io::Stdin`, found struct `std::fs::File`
  |
  = note: expected type `std::io::Stdin`
  = note:    found type `std::fs::File`
note: match arm with an incompatible type
 --> src/main.rs:8:21
  |
8 |             path => File::open(&path).unwrap(),
  |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It doesn't seem like it's possible to polymorphically match trait implementers [(related)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126683/how-to-match-trait-implementors). How can I use either a `File` or `Stdin` as a reader?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is that `stdin()` returns an object of type `Stdio` and `File::open(...).unwrap()` returns an object of type `File`. In Rust, all arms of a match have to return values of the same type.

In this case you probably wanted to return a common `Read` object. Unfortunately `Read` is a trait so you cannot pass it by value. The easiest alternative is to resort to heap allocation:

```
use std::{env, io};
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    for arg in env::args().skip(1) {
        let reader = match arg.as_str() {
            "-" => Box::new(io::stdin()) as Box<Read>,
            path => Box::new(File::open(&path).unwrap()) as Box<Read>,
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Here's a variation on [Lukas's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32934291/234590) answer that avoids boxing:

```
use std::io::{self, Read};
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    if let Some(arg) = std::env::args().nth(1).as_ref() {
        let stdin;
        let file;
        let reader = match arg.as_ref() {
            "-"  => {
                stdin = io::stdin();
                &stdin as &Read
            }
            path => {
                file = File::open(&Path::new(path)).unwrap();
                &file as &Read
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The trick here is to use `let` bindings that are only initialized on some code paths, while still having a long enough lifetime to be able to use them as the target of a borrowed pointer.

Comment: Nice! Of course, this sadly won't work if all this is in another function like `open_reader`. But a nice idea, indeed.

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer does not work with **Rust `v1.0`** anymore. The main statement is still true though: Match arms have to return the same types. Allocating the objects on the heap solves the problem.

```
use std::io::{self, Read};
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    if let Some(arg) = std::env::args().nth(1).as_ref() {
        let reader = match arg.as_ref() {
            "-"  => Box::new(io::stdin()) as Box<Read>,
            path => Box::new(File::open(&Path::new(path)).unwrap()) as Box<Read>,
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The [`coalesce`](https://crates.io/crates/coalesce) crate provides a way to do this without boxing and in a way that is less verbose than [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32937869/234590). The idea is to use a simple enum that can hold the concrete type corresponding to each arm and a macro (`coalesce!`) that expands to a `match` where the body expression is the same for each arm.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate coalesce;

use std::io::{self, Read};
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;
use coalesce::Coalesce2;

fn main() {
    if let Some(arg) = std::env::args().nth(1).as_ref() {
        let reader = match arg.as_ref() {
            "-"  => Coalesce2::A(io::stdin()),
            path => Coalesce2::B(File::open(&Path::new(path)).unwrap()),
        };

        let reader = coalesce!(2 => |ref reader| reader as &Read);

        // the previous line is equivalent to:
        let reader = match reader {
            Coalesce2::A(ref reader) => reader as &Read,
            Coalesce2::B(ref reader) => reader as &Read,
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on @FrancisGagné's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40197458/401059): While the `coalesce` crate is more general, in this case, [`either` will also do](https://docs.rs/either/latest/either/enum.Either.html#impl-Read-for-Either%3CL%2C%20R%3E), and is a little less verbose:

```rust
use std::{env, fs::File, io};
use either::Either;

fn main() {
    for arg in env::args().skip(1) {
        let mut reader = match arg.as_str() {
            "-" => Either::Right(io::stdin()),
            path => Either::Left(File::open(&path).unwrap()),
        };
        // just for show: Either implements Read!
        let reader: &mut dyn io::Read = &mut reader;
    }
}
```