# Preventing value from dropping inside generic match

Tags: rust, traits

When attempting to create objects that inherit a trait from within a `match` statement, I find it's necessary to define different external variables for every type of object being matched.  It's necessary to declare the variables outside of the match so that the declarations don't go out of scope.

It's impossible to use a single external variable of type `Trt` since `Trt` is unsized.  It there any way to have the match return an object implementing `Trt` without reverting to this ugly method of defining lots of variables ahead of time?

Here's an example of the problem:

```
enum Enm {
    X1,
    X2,
    X3
}

trait Trt {
    fn foo(&self) -> &'static str;
}

struct A{}
impl Trt for A{
    fn foo(&self) -> &'static str { "A" }
}

struct B{}
impl Trt for B{
    fn foo(&self) -> &'static str { "B" }
}

struct C{}
impl Trt for C{
    fn foo(&self) -> &'static str { "C" }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Enm::X3;

    let mut temp;
    let mut temp2;
    let mut temp3;
    let gen = match x {
        Enm::X1 => {
            temp = A{};
            &mut temp as &mut Trt
        },
        Enm::X2 => {
            temp2 = B{};
            &mut temp2 as &mut Trt
        },
        Enm::X3 => {
            temp3 = C{};
            &mut temp3 as &mut Trt
        },
    };

    println!("{}", gen.foo());
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26378842

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object you create needs to have an owner. Plain reference `&` can not be owner, that's why you need `temp`/`temp2`/`temp3` in your code to serve as owner of the object you create in `match` arms.

The simplest way to own a trait object is to use `Box` like below:

```
// definitions omitted...
fn main() {
    let x = Enm::X3;

    let gen = match x {
        Enm::X1 => {
            Box::new(A{}) as Box<Trt>
        },
        Enm::X2 => {
            Box::new(B{}) as Box<Trt>
        },
        Enm::X3 => {
            Box::new(C{}) as Box<Trt>
        },
    };

    println!("{}", gen.foo());
}
```

After the match clause, now `gen` owns the created trait object, so you don't have to define temporaries anymore.

Comment: Ahh, thinking of everything having to have an owner makes it a lot more clear.  Thanks for the great reply!