# How to implement Display on a trait object where the types already implement Display

Tags: rust, traits

I have some code which returns a trait object of type `MyTrait` so that it can return one of several different structs. I would like to implement the `Display` trait for the trait object so that I can print the object, with the details delegated to the various structs as they each need their own custom formatters.

I can achieve this by including a formatting method as part of the `MyTrait` definition, and then implementing `Display` for `MyTrait` and delegating - like this:

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn is_even(&self) -> bool;
    fn my_fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result;
}

impl fmt::Display for MyTrait {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        self.my_fmt(f)
    }
}
```

However, I already have the `Display` trait implemented for each of the structs which implement `MyTrait`. This means I end up with two methods for each struct which do the same thing - the `fmt()` method to satisfy the `Display` trait directly on the struct, and the `my_fmt()` method which is called by the code above. This seems clumsy and repetitive. Is there a simpler way to do it?

Here's a complete example program which illustrates the point. It's a little longer than I would have liked (it's based on the answer to my previous question [Calling functions which return different types with shared trait and pass to other functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54470036/calling-functions-which-return-different-types-with-shared-trait-and-pass-to-oth/54470897)), but I couldn't think of a simpler way to illustrate the point. Of course, in this toy example the structs and the `fmt` functions are very simple; in my real application they are more complex.

```
use std::fmt;

trait MyTrait {
    fn is_even(&self) -> bool;
    fn my_fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result;
}

struct First {
    v: u8,
}

struct Second {
    v: Vec<u8>,
}

impl MyTrait for First {
    fn is_even(&self) -> bool {
        self.v % 2 == 0
    }

    fn my_fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.v)
    }
}

impl MyTrait for Second {
    fn is_even(&self) -> bool {
        self.v[0] % 2 == 0
    }

    fn my_fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.v[0])
    }
}

fn make1() -> First {
    First { v: 5 }
}

fn make2() -> Second {
    Second { v: vec![2, 3, 5] }
}

// Implement Display for the structs and for MyTrait
impl fmt::Display for First {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.v)
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for Second {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.v[0])
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for MyTrait {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        self.my_fmt(f)
    }
}

fn requires_mytrait<T: MyTrait + ?Sized>(v: &&T) {
    println!("{:?}", v.is_even());
}

fn main() {
    for i in 0..2 {
        let v1;
        let v2;
        let v = match i {
            0 => {
                v1 = make1();
                println!("> {}", v1); // Demonstrate that Display
                                      // is implemented directly
                                      // on the type.
                &v1 as &MyTrait
            }
            _ => {
                v2 = make2();
                println!("> {}", v2); // Demonstrate that Display
                                      // is implemented directly
                                      // on the type.
                &v2 as &MyTrait
            }
        };
        requires_mytrait(&v);
        println!("{}", v); // Here I print the trait object
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest a simpler, cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make `Display` a supertrait of `MyTrait`.

```
trait MyTrait: fmt::Display {
    fn is_even(&self) -> bool;
}
```

This will make trait objects of `MyTrait` be `Display`. This only works if you expect all implementors of `MyTrait` to implement `Display`, but that was also the case in your previous solution.