# How to get a reference to a concrete type from a trait object?

Tags: rust, traits

How do I get `Box<B>` or `&B` or `&Box<B>` from the `a` variable in this code:

```
trait A {}

struct B;
impl A for B {}

fn main() {
    let mut a: Box<dyn A> = Box::new(B);
    let b = a as Box<B>;
}
```

This code returns an error:

```
error[E0605]: non-primitive cast: `std::boxed::Box<dyn A>` as `std::boxed::Box<B>`
 --> src/main.rs:8:13
  |
8 |     let b = a as Box<B>;
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types. Consider using the `From` trait
```

Answer (score 148, accepted):

There are two ways to do downcasting in Rust.  The first is to use [`Any`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html).  Note that this *only* allows you to downcast to the exact, original concrete type.  Like so:

```
use std::any::Any;

trait A {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

struct B;

impl A for B {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a: Box<dyn A> = Box::new(B);
    // The indirection through `as_any` is because using `downcast_ref`
    // on `Box<A>` *directly* only lets us downcast back to `&A` again.
    // The method ensures we get an `Any` vtable that lets us downcast
    // back to the original, concrete type.
    let b: &B = match a.as_any().downcast_ref::<B>() {
        Some(b) => b,
        None => panic!("&a isn't a B!"),
    };
}
```

The other way is to implement a method for each "target" on the base trait (in this case, `A`), and implement the casts for each desired target type.

---

**Wait, why do we need `as_any`?**

Even if you add `Any` as a requirement for `A`, it's still not going to work correctly.  The first problem is that the `A` in `Box<dyn A>` will *also* implement `Any`... meaning that when you call `downcast_ref`, you'll actually be calling it on the object type `A`.  `Any` can *only* downcast to the type it was invoked on, which in this case is `A`, so you'll only be able to cast back down to `&dyn A` which you already had.

But there's an implementation of `Any` for the underlying type in there *somewhere*, right?  Well, yes, but you can't get at it.  Rust doesn't allow you to "cross cast" from `&dyn A` to `&dyn Any`.

*That* is what `as_any` is for; because it's something only implemented on our "concrete" types, the compiler doesn't get confused as to which one it's supposed to invoke.  Calling it on an `&dyn A` causes it to dynamically dispatch to the concrete implementation (again, in this case, `B::as_any`), which returns an `&dyn Any` using the implementation of `Any` for `B`, which is what we want.

Note that you *can* side-step this whole problem by just not using `A` *at all*.  Specifically, the following will *also* work:

```
fn main() {
    let a: Box<dyn Any> = Box::new(B);
    let _: &B = match a.downcast_ref::<B>() {
        Some(b) => b,
        None => panic!("&a isn't a B!")
    };    
}
```

However, this precludes you from having any *other* methods; *all* you can do here is downcast to a concrete type.

As a final note of potential interest, the [mopa](https://crates.io/crates/mopa) crate allows you to combine the functionality of `Any` with a trait of your own.

Comment: It's worth pointing out why the `as_any` function is needed. This is implemented for `B` and takes a parameter `self` of type `&B`, which is converted to a `&Any` and can later be cast back to a `&B`. Were `a.as_any()` to be replaced with `(&*a as &Any)` it could only be cast back to the type converted to `&Any`, that is `&A`. `&A` and `&B` are not the same thing since they have differing v-tables.

Comment: I have been looking for this answer for a full day now. Sometimes Rust feels very counter-intuitive.

Comment: For the next googler: it may be easier for you to just use the [downcast-rs](https://crates.io/crates/downcast-rs) crate.

Comment: Isn't that 'issue' with `as_any` solved by now? I just stumbled upon an example where the downcast is called on `Box` directly: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#impl-Box%3Cdyn%20Any%20+%20Send%20+%20%27static%2C%20A%3E

Comment: For the comment about "downcast-rs", just for casting, I wouldn't want to use another crate. That must be handled using pure rust.

Answer (score 9):

It should be clear that the cast can fail if there is another type `C` implementing `A` and you try to cast `Box<C>` into a `Box<B>`. I don't know your situation, but to me it looks a lot like you are bringing techniques from other languages, like Java, into Rust. I've never encountered this kind of Problem in Rust -- maybe your code design could be improved to avoid this kind of cast.

If you want, you can "cast" pretty much anything with [`mem::transmute`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html). Sadly, we will have a problem if we just want to cast `Box<A>` to `Box<B>` or `&A` to `&B` because a pointer to a `trait` is a fat-pointer that actually consists of two pointers: One to the actual object, one to the vptr. If we're casting it to a `struct` type, we can just ignore the vptr. Please remember that this solution is highly unsafe and pretty hacky -- I wouldn't use it in "real" code.

```
let (b, vptr): (Box<B>, *const ()) = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(a) };
```

EDIT: Screw that, it's even more unsafe than I thought. If you want to do it correctly this way you'd have to use [`std::raw::TraitObject`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/raw/struct.TraitObject.html). This is still unstable though. I don't think that this is of any use to OP; don't use it!

There are better alternatives in this very similar question: [How to match trait implementors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126683/how-to-match-trait-implementors)