# How can I specify `Sized` for boxed value

Tags: rust

I want to notify that "this method will return boxed `Struct` which implements `Trait` and `Sized`".
Simple resolution is just put `Struct` into `Box` but I can't because `Struct` has so big generic parameter that I can't write manually.

```
// I can't edit these trait and struct.
trait Trait {}
struct Struct();
impl Trait for Struct {}

// This is my code.
fn func() -> Box<Trait> {
    Box::new(Struct{})
}

// This is not my code.
fn need_sized<T: Trait + Sized>(item: T) {
    println!("ok");
}

fn main() {
    // This can not be compiled!
    need_sized(func());
}
```

I can edit `func` function but I can't others.

How can I specify that Trait implements Sized?
Is it something kind like below?

```
fn func() -> Box<Trait + Sized>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the specification the only way you can bypass this is to make [newtype wrapper](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-the-newtype-pattern-to-implement-external-traits-on-external-types).

```
// I can't edit these trait and struct.
trait Trait {}
struct Struct();
impl Trait for Struct {}


// This is my code.
struct MyStruct(Struct);
impl Trait for Box<MyStruct> { /* if there is code here delegate to inner `Struct` */}

fn func() -> Box<MyStruct> {
    Box::new(MyStruct(Struct{}))
}

// This is not my code.
fn need_sized<T: Trait + Sized>(item: T) {
    println!("ok");
}

fn main() {
    // This can not be compiled!
    need_sized(func());
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4de7e0ccdabff976c25b932a13f9bbb9&version=nightly&backtrace=0)

Why other approaches won't solve your issues:

1. Monomorphisized trait

   `fn func<T: Trait>() -> Box<T> { ... }`

You want to pass `func` to `need_size`. More specifically, you want to pass `Box` to the `need_size` function.

2. Changing function signature to `Box<Struct>`

> error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::boxed::Box<Struct>: Trait` is not satisfied

> ```
> --> <anon>:22:5
> ```

```
  |
22|     need_sized(func());
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Trait` is not implemented for   `std::boxed::Box<Struct>`
  |= help: the following implementations were found:
         <std::boxed::Box<MyStruct> as Trait>
   = note: required by `need_sized`
```

This won't work because you can't control either `Box` or `Struct` since they aren't defined in you crate, and it would mess up with coherence rules. In future this might be solved using special coherence rules.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: A [type alias](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/type-aliases.html) may also work with less verbosity (and less flexibility).

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to be able to change either `func` or `need_sized` for this to work. As they are, `func` returns a [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html) which is unsized, while `need_sized` requires a concrete type (more than that, it requires full ownership of its parameter `item`, not just a reference).

Approach 1: if you control and can change `func()`, you can change it to return a `Box<Struct>` instead of `Box<Trait>`:

```
fn func() -> Box<Struct> {
    Box::new(Struct{})
}

fn main() {
    let s1 = func(); // Box<Struct>, needs dereferencing with *
                     // to become a Struct
    need_sized(*s1); // this now works
}
```

Approach 2: if you don't control `func()` but do control `need_sized` and `Trait` you can downcast the Box back to a Struct as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33687996/497364

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4de7e0ccdabff976c25b932a13f9bbb9&version=nightly&backtrace=0)

```
use std::any::Any; // needed for downcast

trait Trait {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &Any;
}

struct Struct{}
impl Trait for Struct {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &Any {
        self
    }
}

fn func() -> Box<Trait> {
    Box::new(Struct{})
}


// changed to accept a &T
fn need_sized<T: Trait + Sized>(_item: &T) { 
    println!("ok");
}

fn main() {
    let s2 = func(); 
    if let Some(st) = s2.as_any().downcast_ref::<Struct>() {
        need_sized(st);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for nice answer. But what makes this problem difficult is I can't write `Struct` simply. Because `Struct` has so big generic parameter that I can't write simply. Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: @AtsukiTakahashi If typing is your primary concern, you may be able to just make a [type alias](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/type-aliases.html) (e.g. `type Short<T> = Long<'a, T, Box<Trait + 'static>>` or what have you, and then use `Short<T>` instead of the long version.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is;

> error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::boxed::Box<Trait>: Trait` is not satisfied

So adding;
`impl Trait for Box<Trait> {}`
after line three lets it compile.

Comment: Thanks for answered. So in case we can't `impl Trait for Box<Trait>` (ex. `Trait` is not our code), how do we do?

Comment: Try using a newtype struct.

Comment: I think this [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/second-edition/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#the-newtype-pattern-to-implement-external-traits-on-external-types) explains what you may need to do.