# Is it possible to downcast Rc<RefCell<MyTrait>> to a generic Rc<RefCell<MyStruct<T>>>?

Tags: rust

I have defined these:

```
struct MyStruct<T> { /* ... */ }

trait MyTrait: Any { /* ... */ }

impl<T> MyTrait for MyStruct<T> { /* ... */ }
```

Is it possible to downcast `Rc<RefCell<MyTrait>>` to `Rc<RefCell<MyStruct<T>>>` (in the context of a function generic on `T`)?

```
fn some_fn<T>(h: &HashMap<String, Rc<RefCell<MyTrait>>>, key: &str) -> Rc<RefCell<MyStruct<T>>> {
    let x: Rc<RefCell<MyTrait>> = h.get(key).unwrap().clone();
    /* what goes here ??? */ (x)
}
```

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How to get a struct reference from a boxed trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33687447/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I actually meant to return the downcasted reference, so getting a reference to MyStruct with non-static lifetime is not sufficient.

Comment: This is surprisingly difficult, because you can't cross-cast from `Rc<RefCell<MyTrait>>` to `Rc<RefCell<Any>>`, and you can't use an `as_any` method on `MyTrait` because `Rc<RefCell<Self>>` isn't a valid receiver. `transmute` would appear to be your only option.

Comment: But what should `some_fn<i32>` do when the `HashMap` contains an `Rc<RefCell<String>>`? You have to account for failure somehow (e.g. by panicking, or returning an `Option`).

Comment: @trentcl: if the type does not match, it's fine to just panic.   Regarding transmuting, is there a recommended way to do that?   Are they bit-compatible?