# In order to downcast a trait object why does it have to be static?

Tags: rust

The `std::error::Error` trait is transiting to a new design. Noticeably its `cause` method:

```rust
fn cause(&self) -> Option<&dyn Error>
```

is deprecated and to be replaced by:

```rust
fn source(&self) -> Option<&(dyn Error + 'static)>
```

Besides the name, the only change is that the new method returns `'static`. The reason given by [fix error RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2504-fix-error.md#why-cause---source) is:

> The problem with the existing `cause` API is that the error it returns is not `'static`. This means it is not possible to downcast the error trait object, because downcasting can only be done on `'static` trait objects (for soundness reasons).

This is not obvious to me at all. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to understand it is to implement one! This SO question:

- [How to get a reference to a concrete type from a trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687447/how-to-get-a-reference-to-a-concrete-type-from-a-trait-object)

is a good starting point. The implementation in it relies on `std::any::Any` but doesn't shed light on why `'static` is required. If it is to be implemented directly in the same vein as `(dyn Any)::downcast_ref()` though ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1c457fab89fb59477ede538d490ebe16)):

```rust
use std::any::TypeId;

trait A {
    fn type_id(&self) -> TypeId
    where
        Self: 'static,
    {
        TypeId::of::<Self>()
    }
}

impl dyn A + 'static {
    fn is<T: A + 'static>(&self) -> bool {
        let t = TypeId::of::<T>();
        let concrete = self.type_id();

        t == concrete
    }

    fn downcast_ref<T: A + 'static>(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        if self.is::<T>() {
            unsafe { Some(&*(self as *const dyn A as *const T)) }
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

struct B;

impl A for B {}

fn main() {
    let a: Box<dyn A> = Box::new(B);

    let _b: &B = match a.downcast_ref::<B>() {
        Some(b) => b,
        None => panic!("&a isn't a B!"),
    };
}
```

The `unsafe` here is actually safe because we are only downcasting back to the original type thanks to the type id check. The implementation pivots on [`TypeId`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/any/struct.TypeId.html) to give us that guarantee:

> A TypeId is currently only available for types which ascribe to 'static, but this limitation may be removed in the future.

If digging a little bit deeper, the way [how this type id is calculated at the moment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.40.0/src/librustc_codegen_llvm/debuginfo/doc.rs#L166) finally gives us the answer. That is, a struct `Struct<'a>` may have N instantiations with different concrete substitutions for `'a`, but the type id is the same. Were the `TypeId` to be available to all `Struct<'a>`, we then can downcast any `Struct<'a>` to `Struct<'static>`, which would be a soundness issue.