# Trait with function without "self" as parameter cannot be made into an object

Tags: rust, traits

I am trying to build a entity component system as part of my journey to learn Rust.
I had an idea where each component would have a static id, and objects would have a HashMap of the components it contains (with the limit of one component per type).

Here is the object itself:

```
pub struct Object {
    // TODO : components !
    components: HashMap<i32, Box<dyn Component>>
}

impl Object {
    pub fn add_component<C: Component>(&self) {
        self.components.insert(C::id(), Box::new(C::new()));
    }

    pub fn get_component<C: Component>(&self) -> Option<&C> {
        return self.components.get(C::id())
    }
}
```

And here is my Component trait:

```
pub trait Component {
    fn id() -> i32 {
        // one must ensure this returns different id for every component
        return 0;
    }

    fn new<C: Component>() -> C;

    fn require_rendering(&self) -> bool {
        return false;
    }

    fn some_function_on_component(&mut self) {
        // do something on the component 
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get this error :
"this trait cannot be made into an object...
...because associated function `id` has no `self` parameter"

Could anyone explain why does this not work, and how to work around it?

Comment: How is hardcoding 0, instead of returning a unique value you get from inspecting `self`, compatible with ensuring that each component has a different id?

Comment: It will still now work in this case because `new()` is generic. `where Self: Sized` may work.

Comment: The `new` function should probably be `fn new() -> Self;`, unless you intend for every possible `Component` implementation to serve as a potential factory for every other possible implementing type.

Comment: And this is not object safe either.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Reading the rest of the code, I think the idea is that each _type_ has a unique ID.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I did not say that it was, only pointing out the conceptual problem with the generic argument.

Comment: This is not completely related to your question, but rather to your general purpose: IIRC, ECS tend not to store components within entities (if that's what your `Object` is supposed to represent), but rather have a single big table that maps entities to their components. In this model, an entity is just an identifier to an entry in that table.

Comment: @BlackBeans Thanks for the info ! but does that implies that entities have all the data ? for exemple, if I want a 'Mesh' component, containing vertices and triangles, I'd rather keep that data in the component struct instead of the entity itself.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not sure to understand what you meant ? the idea was that each type of component imlementing 'Component' would have a hard-coded different id when implementing that function 'id'

Comment: @LucioleMaléfique I think you misunderstand. He is talking about your map, if I understand correctly. He means that instead of storing the components in a map of your 'object' class, the map in your object class should only store references to the components. The components itself should be in a big table, one table per component type.
I don't think it's relevant for you now at the beginning. But it enables looping over, say all "position/velocity" components easily and quickly for physics updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of those are fairly easily fixable by following the compiler messages.

The biggest hurdle I came across while trying to get your code to compile is to [downcast the `Box<dyn>` back to its original type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687447/how-to-get-a-reference-to-a-concrete-type-from-a-trait-object).

That's my attempt, I have no idea if it actually does something in the end, but at least it compiles :)

```rust
use std::any::Any;
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub struct Object {
    // TODO : components !
    components: HashMap<i32, Box<dyn Component>>,
}

impl Object {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            components: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn add_component<C: 'static + Component>(&mut self) {
        self.components.insert(C::id(), Box::new(C::new()));
    }

    pub fn get_component<C: 'static + Component>(&self) -> Option<&C> {
        self.components
            .get(&C::id())
            .map(|boxed_component| boxed_component.as_any().downcast_ref::<C>().unwrap())
    }
}

pub trait Component {
    fn id() -> i32
    where
        Self: Sized;

    fn new() -> Self
    where
        Self: Sized;

    fn require_rendering(&self) -> bool {
        return false;
    }

    fn some_function_on_component(&mut self) {
        // do something on the component
    }

    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}
```

Things I've done:

- Add `Self: Sized` to `id()` and `new()`. Both of those are trait functions and therefore have to be resolved at runtime. The step of resolving the type requires something called a "vtable", which only exists on types that actually have a size. (that's at least my understanding of the problem)
- Replace the generic parameter on `new` with `Self`, as this is what you probably actually want.
- Add `mut` to `self` in `add_component`
- Remove default implementation of `id()` to actually force implementing structs to overwrite it
- Downcast the `&dyn Component` to the actual component type in `get_component`, based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687447/how-to-get-a-reference-to-a-concrete-type-from-a-trait-object). Of course there are probably different solutions, I just picked that one because I didn't feel like doing any further research :)

I didn't solve the problem that you currently only get non-mutable objects out of `get_component`. This will probably be the next thing you will tackle.

All in all, here is a minimal working example of your code with a "Name" and an "Age" component, just to demonstrate that your approach is feasible:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5d22b64ab924394606a07a043594f608

Comment: Dang. I just spent part of my day to make the system works, and most of the things I have done is what you said ! Thanks a lot !
Slight modification : 
I've added a 'on_added' function in the component trait, if any components need to be initialized, other than in the 'new' function, and the last thing I can't do yet :
I would like the 'add_component' method to return a reference to the component, but I'm not good enough with lifetimes to think of a smart way to do this.
Anyways, you solved it ! Thanks again !

Comment: For returning a reference from the add_component method, you should take a look at the `HashMap::entry` function.
Here is [my attempt](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=916013f2d327d8fe52681750162624ac). Of course, I recommend trying it yourself first before looking at what I did.