# Can't downcast from &mut Box<dyn Trait> as &mut dyn Any?

Tags: rust, downcast

I encountered this issue, and I'm wondering why it doesn't work.
I managed to replicate the problem :

I'm trying to get back to the struct from `&mut Box<dyn Trait>`, and this is my go at it:

```rust
use std::any::Any;

trait A {}

struct B;

impl A for B {}

fn main() {
    let mut a: Box<dyn A> = Box::new(B);
    let a_ref: &mut Box<dyn A> = &mut a;

    match (a_ref as &mut dyn Any).downcast_mut::<B>() { // downcast here 
        Some(_b) => println!("found b"),
        None => println!("found nothing")
    }
}
```

But this does not find the struct behind it ? Am I missing something ?

Here is a link [to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9a2de5a11e8a495e026bf63e97f0b3ef)

I've tried to downcast to other things, such as `Box<B>` or `&mut B` but none if this works.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just say `my_trait_object as &dyn Any` and expect to be able to downcast to the original type. It does not work by magic, you need the *original* type to coerce itself as `dyn Any`, that's the only way it works. That is why the solutions here need to pass through the trait object, to get at the original type, to get it as an `Any`: [How to get a reference to a concrete type from a trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33687447/2189130)

What happens here is that a concrete type is coerced into a `dyn Any`, but that concrete type is `Box<dyn A>`. This code prints "found box":

```
use std::any::Any;

trait A {}
struct B;
impl A for B {}

fn main() {
    let mut a: Box<dyn A> = Box::new(B);
    let a_ref: &mut Box<dyn A> = &mut a;

    match (a_ref as &mut dyn Any).downcast_mut::<Box<dyn A>>() {
        Some(_) => println!("found box"),
        None => println!("found nothing"),
    }
}
```

There's more explanation in the linked answers that I encourage you to read.

Comment: In the link you gave, there is a suggestion about implementing ```as_any() -> &dyn Any``` on the trait, and it works. How is this different from my ```as &dyn Any``` ? 
And by getting back to the ```Box<dyn A>```, I'm back at the starting point.

Comment: @LucioleMaléfique The solution in the link is the only way to downcast into the original concrete type. When you do `&mut a as &mut dyn Any` you have already lost any association with the original concrete type. The `.as_any()` trick works because it *can* access the original type *through* the `dyn A` implementation.