# Rust casting to &dyn Any

Tags: rust

I want to make a function that counts occurencies of the actual type in a slice.

```
struct Struct1;
struct Struct2;

trait Lol {}

impl Lol for Struct1 {}
impl Lol for Struct2 {}

fn countActualTypes<T>(s: &[&dyn Lol]) -> u32 {   
    let mut cnt = 0;        
    s.iter().for_each(|e| {   // (1) e type is &&dyn Lol so *e is &dyn Lol "seems ok"
        if (*e as &dyn Any).is::<T>() { // (2)
            cnt += 1;
        }        
    });   
    cnt
}

fn main() {
    let slice = [&Struct1 as &dyn Lol, &Struct2 as &dyn Lol].as_slice();
    assert_eq!(1, countActualTypes::<Struct1>(slice));    
}
```

It gives error at (2): **error[E0605]: non-primitive cast: &dyn Lol as `&(dyn Any + 'static)**.

So I thought the reason is the default 'static lifetime of dyn Any and changed the function to this:

```
fn countActualTypes<'a, T>(s: &[&'a dyn Lol]) -> u32 {   
    let mut cnt = 0;        
    s.iter().for_each(|e| {   // e type is &&dyn Lol (1)
        if (*e as &'a dyn Any).is::<T>() {
            cnt += 1;
        }        
    });   
    cnt
}
```

Same error.
Next I tried this:

```
fn countActualTypes<'a, T>(s: &[&(dyn Lol + 'a)]) -> u32 {   
    let mut cnt = 0;        
    s.iter().for_each(|e| {   // e type is &&dyn Lol (1)
        if (*e as &(dyn Any + 'a)).is::<T>() {
            cnt += 1;
        }        
    });   
    cnt
}
```

Error: **error[E0605]: non-primitive cast: `&dyn Lol` as `&(dyn Any + 'a)`**

Q1. Does **&(dyn Lol + 'a)** and **&'a dyn Lol** differ?

Q2. How to make it work?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for answering, I finally came to:

```
trait Lol: Any {}

fn countActualTypes<T: 'static>(s: &[&dyn Lol]) -> u32 {   
    let mut cnt = 0;        
    s.iter().for_each(|e| {       
        if (*e).type_id() == TypeId::of::<T>() {
            cnt += 1;
        }          
    });   
    cnt
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Does `&(dyn Lol + 'a)` and `&'a dyn Lol` differ?

Not really. Both just make [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html) explicit, in different aspects of it.

> How to make it work?

You cannot convert from `Lol` to `Any` unless you built this conversion for the trait `Lol`. For how, see [How to get a reference to a concrete type from a trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687447/how-to-get-a-reference-to-a-concrete-type-from-a-trait-object).