# How to downcast a Trait in rust directly from the Trait itself

Tags: rust

In this question:

[How to get a reference to a concrete type from a trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687447/how-to-get-a-reference-to-a-concrete-type-from-a-trait-object)

Explains how to use `Any` to downcast a Trait. But I would like to downcast directly from the Trait to all the supported known types instead of using a generic `as_any` method. I tried:

```
pub trait A{
    fn as_B(&self) -> B {
        (&self as &dyn Any).downcast_ref::<B>().expect("Can't cast to B").clone()
    }
}
impl A for B{}
```

But I get the error: lifetime may not live long enough cast requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`

I have tried:

1. Mark trait A as Clone, but this is not an option since this break other Traits that uses A and need those traits to be object traits.
2. Put life time parameters in the trait. This litter a lot of places where my trait A is used and in the end I get the same compilation error.
3. Remove & from self. But is neither an option since A size is not known.

Comment: What should `as_B` do if called on something other then `B`?

Comment: Why can't you add a `as_any()` method, as suggested in the answer?

Answer (score -3):

Edited:

If you just want what Any does without going through it here [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e755892c36b5b20fd8ff29472c2369be), this is UB since Any is meant to translate to [usable type](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dfe58e086305f680bf7f3b9cb2404999),

```
trait A{
    // Edited from std::any::Any downcast_ref_unchecked there is a checked version if you want to look
    fn downcast_ref_unchecked(&self) -> &B where Self: Sized{
            // Don't ask me how this works but I believe it dips into C land of pointers
            unsafe { &*(self as *const dyn A as *const B) }
    }
}
// Target
#[derive(Debug)]
struct B;

// Test
#[derive(Debug)]
struct C;

// Have test struct have 'A' trait
impl A for C {}

fn main(){
    let t = C{};
    println!("{:?}", t.downcast_ref_unchecked());
    println!("{:?}", t);
}
```

Comment: This answer is UB, unless either `B` is the only implementor (i.e. the downcast is always correct) or `B` is zero-sized (i.e. there are no fields to be accessed from reference to it).

Comment: @rsan It was downvotes probably because it is terribly unsound. There is a reason std's `downcast_unchecked()` is marked unsafe.

Comment: What they are asking for is UB already, since Any just allows anything to be a argument in a function, and downcast functions are meant to turn the Any to appropriate type for use.