# Implementing Type-Safe Factory Methods for Generic Types in Rust

Tags: rust, dynamic, polymorphism

Newbie to Rust here, though I have spent quite some time in low-level / kernel driver / embedded C and have some light experience with C++11 and newer.  I suspect part of my problem will be un-learning old habits.

How would I implement a type-safe method that constructs objects which implement a give trait yet require a generic parameter themselves?

This project in question is a simple MQTT to Prometheus bridge; the goal here is to be able to parse a config file and then call `register_metric` on each configured item to return an object which the MQTT side can later use to update the value (via the `UpdateFromString` trait) when a publish comes in.  Consider (trimmed for brevity):

```
enum MetricType { IntegerCounter, FloatCounter, IntegerGauge, FloatGauge }

pub trait UpdateFromString {
    fn update_from_string(&self, value: String);
}

impl UpdateFromString for prometheus::Counter {
    fn update_from_string(&self, value: String) {
        self.inc();
    }
}

// snip - impl UpdateFromString for other Prometheus types we support

struct PrometheusEndpoint { ... }

impl PrometheusEndpoint
{
    fn new(runtime: std::rc::Rc<tokio::runtime::Runtime>) -> Result<PrometheusEndpoint, i32> { ... }

    async fn metrics_handler(registry: std::sync::Arc<prometheus::Registry>) -> Result<impl warp::Reply, std::convert::Infallible> { ... }

    fn register_metric(&self, name: String, desc: String, mtype: MetricType) -> Box<impl UpdateFromString>
    {
        let metric: Box<dyn std::any::Any>;

        // Instantiate raw metric type
        match mtype {
            MetricType::IntegerCounter => metric = Box::new(prometheus::IntCounter::new(name, desc).unwrap()),
            MetricType::IntegerGauge   => metric = Box::new(prometheus::IntGauge::new(name, desc).unwrap()),
            MetricType::FloatCounter   => metric = Box::new(prometheus::Counter::new(name, desc).unwrap()),
            MetricType::FloatGauge     => metric = Box::new(prometheus::Gauge::new(name, desc).unwrap()),
            _ => panic!("Unknown metric type"),
        };

        // Register metric with registry
        // NOTE: After this completes, this metric can potentially be scraped by the remote Prometheus instance
        self.registry.register(metric.clone()).unwrap();

        // We implement UpateFromString on the Prometheus base types above so we can just return them directly.
        // This is safe since Rust won't let us use any functions not specified via our trait so a container
        // object is just redundant.
        metric
    }
}
```

I define my own input enum to hide Prometheus from the rest of the application which I think might be part of the problem.  If I did this fully statically (i.e. `fn register_metric<T>(&self, name: String, desc: String) -> Box<impl UpdateFromString>`) this is pretty trivial but requires leaking the raw Prometheus types to the config parsing logic.  It also doesn't limit me to the Prometheus types only.

The other way would be to use dynamic dispatch, which is what I attempted above.  That said, I am not sure how to declare the proper types to make the compiler happy.  Untimately, it appears to be unhappy that I doesn't know the final storage size at compile time.  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687447/how-to-get-a-reference-to-a-concrete-type-from-a-trait-object) SO post seems to indicate that `std::any::Any` should work and `Box<Any>` makes sense to my C-brain as a type-safe version of C's `struct foo myvar = *((struct foo *)malloc(sizeof struct foo))`.  Unfortunately, this still gives unknown size at compile time errors; which makes sense given that the Box will have the size of at least the inner type which is now variable.

AFAICT, even a `Rc` / `Arc` won't work as that signature would have to be something like `Rc<Box<foo>>` which just brings the whole different-sized type thing one level deeper.

So, as stated above, **what it a type-safe way to construct and return one of a supported list of types which implement a given trait *and* accept generic parameters?**

Some final notes:

- Usage of `Box` in required by Prometheus when registering new metrics.
- The `registry` object is created in `new`; the use of `Box.clone()` is copy-pasts from the Prometheus examples (though I don't fully appreciate why this is necessary).
- I would *really* like to do this without `unsafe` if at all possible.
- I would prefer not to use external crates if possible; implementing "the hard way" is far more instructive to me.

Comment: What is the full error from `cargo check`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is *type erasure*. You are partially achieving it by returning a `impl Trait` existential type, but to go all the way there you gotta use a dynamically dispatched object, `dyn Trait`, behind some kind of indirection. Which, luckily, you already have in the form of `Box`.

Here's what I propose your `register_metric` should look like:

```rs
    fn register_metric(&self, name: String, desc: String, mtype: MetricType) -> Box<dyn UpdateFromString>
    {
        // Instantiate raw metric type
        let metric = match mtype {
            MetricType::IntegerCounter => Box::new(prometheus::IntCounter::new(name, desc).unwrap()),
            MetricType::IntegerGauge   => Box::new(prometheus::IntGauge::new(name, desc).unwrap()),
            MetricType::FloatCounter   => Box::new(prometheus::Counter::new(name, desc).unwrap()),
            MetricType::FloatGauge     => Box::new(prometheus::Gauge::new(name, desc).unwrap()),
            _ => panic!("Unknown metric type"),
        };

        // Register metric with registry
        // NOTE: After this completes, this metric can potentially be scraped by the remote Prometheus instance
        self.registry.register(metric.clone()).unwrap();

        // We implement UpateFromString on the Prometheus base types above so we can just return them directly.
        // This is safe since Rust won't let us use any functions not specified via our trait so a container
        // object is just redundant.
        metric
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the sample as written still doesn't compile for me.  I get `expected 'Box<GenericCounter<AtomicU64>>', found 'Box<GenericGauge<AtomicI64>>` which appears to be a similar form of type confusion (`GenericCounter` and `GenericGauge` are the base types for their respective `int` / `float` implementations).  I notice that whichever clause I put first in the `match` block will be the expected type in the error message.  Doesn't this indicate Rust is still unhappy with the internal type?  Or should `dyn` have cause Rust to only consider the part of the vtable defined by the trait?

Comment: Ah, yes, there's some rough edges to `dyn` coersion. I think adding explicit coersion like `Box::new(... as dyn _)` in the first branch should be enough.

Comment: You can write `let metric: Box<dyn UpdateFromString> = match {...` as another way around that error message.

Comment: I wasn't able to get the explicit coercion working but explicitly typing the metric variable did the trick.