# Filter vector by element type

Tags: rust, filter, traits

Is there a way to implement the function below?

```rust
trait X {}

struct A;
struct B;

impl X for A {}
impl X for B {}

/// Only keep elements of type A
fn filter(list: Vec<Box<dyn X>>) -> Vec<Box<A>> {
    todo!();
}
```

In dart, it could be much easier:

```dart
List<A> filter(list: List<X>) {
     return list.whereType<A>();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use some kind of downcasting. As explained in [How to get a reference to a concrete type from a trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687447/how-to-get-a-reference-to-a-concrete-type-from-a-trait-object), the stable way is to add an `as_any()` method:

```rust
use std::any::Any;

trait X {
    fn as_any_box(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn Any>;
}

struct A;
struct B;

impl X for A {
    fn as_any_box(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn Any> {
        self
    }
}
impl X for B {
    fn as_any_box(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn Any> {
        self
    }
}

/// Only keep elements of type A
fn filter(list: Vec<Box<dyn X>>) -> Vec<Box<A>> {
    list.into_iter()
        .filter_map(|v| v.as_any_box().downcast::<A>().ok())
        .collect()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Chayim gave great answer to your exact question, but I would like to add that if you are able do change slightly your requirements and use *enum dispatch* instead of *dynamic dispatch*, your problem would become trivial.

```rust
use std::iter::Extend;

trait X {}

struct A;
struct B;

impl X for A {}
impl X for B {}

enum DispatchX {
    A(A),
    B(B),
}

impl X for DispatchX {
    // delegate all X's methods to present variant
}

fn filterA(list: Vec<DispatchX>) -> Vec<A> {
    let mut result = Vec::with_capacity(list.len());
    let data = list
        .into_iter()
        .filter_map(|x| {
            match x {
                DispatchX::A(a) => Some(a),
                _ => None,
         }});
    result.extend(data);
    data
}
```

You can automate creating `DispatchX` with crate [enum_dispatch](https://crates.io/crates/enum_dispatch). This will of course only work if there are a finite implementators of trait `X` and all are local to your crate (or at least you don't expect any of your consumers to create one).

Also note that instead of `collecting` iterator into I chose to [extend](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html) previously allocated vector. This will result in no re-allocations, but if you have very few `A` items in your `list`, you might allocate much more memory than you need. If ratio of `A`s to `B`s is predictable, you can manipulate capacity given to `Vec::with_capacity` to improve memory usage.