# How do I get the type of a variable behind a &dyn Trait?

Tags: rust, traits, type-traits

In this following example I try printing out the type of both variable `x` and `y` (both with type `Foo` and `Foo` implements trait `Bar`).

But when passed into a funtion `print_name()`, `x` is passed as `&Foo` but `y` passed as `&dyn Bar`, I got different type names from `x` and `y`:

```
x: &rust_test::Foo
y: &dyn rust_test::Bar
```

How do I fix this program to get a `Foo` when passing a `&dyn Bar` variable into the function?

full code:

```rust
use std::any::type_name;

fn type_of<T: ?Sized>(_: &T) -> String {
    type_name::<T>().to_string()
}

struct Foo {}

trait Bar {}

impl Bar for Foo {}

fn print_name(x: &Foo, y: &dyn Bar) {
    println!("x: {}", type_of(&x));
    println!("y: {}", type_of(&y));
}

fn main() {
    let x = Foo {};
    let y = Foo {};

    print_name(&x, &y);
    /*
    x: &rust_test::Foo
    y: &dyn rust_test::Bar
    */
}
```

Comment: `std::any::type_name()` is intended for debugging purposes only. Do you really need it?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Is there a better way to get the type (ideally in String) of a variable?

Comment: For what purpose? What can you do with it?

Comment: For instance, in this case I hope to find out if `x` and `y` from `print_name` are of the same type

Comment: You can't rely on `type_name()` to do that. You need [`TypeId`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/any/struct.TypeId.html) for that (it'll have the same problem, though).

Comment: You'll have to add a method to the trait like [in this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687447/how-to-get-a-reference-to-a-concrete-type-from-a-trait-object) but you don't actually have to go through `Any`, you can expose `type_id` directly instead indirection through `as_any`.