# Rust trait object's &self cannot be used in a trait default function

Tags: oop, casting, rust, traits

Trying to override a trait cast problem, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126683/how-to-match-trait-implementors). Stuck at implementing the trait function which returns the enum instance with own implementation inside:

```
//the "trait matcher" enum
enum Side<'a> {
    Good(&'a GoodDude),
    Bad(&'a BadDude),
}

//very general trait
trait Dude {
    fn who_am_i(&self) -> Side;
    fn do_useful_stuff(&self);
}

//specific trait #1
trait GoodDude: Dude {
    fn who_am_i_inner(&self) -> Side {
        Side::Good(&self)
    }

    fn save_the_world(&self);
}

//specific trait #2
trait BadDude: Dude {
    fn who_am_i_inner(&self) -> Side {
        Side::Bad(&self)
    }

    fn do_evil(&self);
}
```

But for some reason the compilation of this part fails with [E0277](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0277):

```
trait GoodDude: Dude {        
    fn who_am_i_inner(&self) -> Side {
        Side::Good(&self) //&self should be &GoodDude, but compiler says it is not...
    }

    fn save_the_world(&self);
}
```

And results in:

```
<anon>:16:20: 16:25 error: the trait `GoodDude` is not implemented for the type `&Self` [E0277]
<anon>:16         Side::Good(&self)
                             ^~~~~
<anon>:16:20: 16:25 help: see the detailed explanation for E0277
<anon>:16:20: 16:25 note: required for the cast to the object type `GoodDude`
```

Can this be worked out?

Full sample: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8ae2384e401da76c16214c4a642ce8b4&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: Try `Side::Good(self)` instead of `Side::Good(&self)`.

Comment: I cannot. The implementor of the traits may be a huge struct, I have to use borrows and trait objects there. Besides it immediately asks for Size (the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented)

Comment: `fn name(&self)` can be de-sugared as `fn name(self:&Self)`. Type of the `self` variable is `&Self`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, the type of `self` in `fn who_am_i_inner` is already a reference, so you don't need to `&`.

```
fn who_am_i_inner(&self) -> Side {
    Side::Good(self)
}
```

But then rustc complains...

```
<anon>:13:20: 13:24 error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `Self` [E0277]
<anon>:13         Side::Good(self)
                             ^~~~
<anon>:13:20: 13:24 help: see the detailed explanation for E0277
<anon>:13:20: 13:24 note: `Self` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
<anon>:13:20: 13:24 note: required for the cast to the object type `GoodDude`
```

Admittedly the error message is very unclear and E0277 is about something totally different. Let's try the nightly compiler instead, which gives better error messages:

```
error: the trait bound `Self: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied [--explain E0277]
  --> <anon>:13:20
13 |>         Side::Good(self)
   |>                    ^^^^
help: consider adding a `where Self: std::marker::Sized` bound
note: required for the cast to the object type `GoodDude`
```

OK let's try to add the `where Self: Sized`:

```
fn who_am_i_inner(&self) -> Side where Self: Sized {
    Side::Good(self)
}
```

and now it works.

> World saved. Press any key to continue
>   May the 4th be with you
>   Pew Pew Pew
>   Luke I am yr father

---

The `where Self: Sized` is Rust's way to signify that [the method *cannot* be used from trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html#object-safety). We say the method ignored from "object-safety", or "cannot be virtual" if you like C++.

The effect is that if all you have got is `luke: &GoodDude`, then you cannot call `luke.who_am_i_inner()` since `*luke` has an unknown size.

The reason we need to make the method not object-safe is due to the cast `&Self → &GoodDude`. In Rust a trait object reference like `&GoodDude` is a *fat pointer*, internally it is represented as a 2-tuple `(pointer, method_table)`. However, in a trait the `self` is a thin-pointer.

We cannot convert a thin-pointer to a fat-pointer, since there is a missing information, the method_table. This can be filled in if we knew the concrete type. That's why we add the `where Self: Sized`.

If you want to make `who_am_i_inner` object-safe, then you cannot provide a default implementation.

Comment: Thanks. This explicitly describes what I need. Now at least I can use this approach as a form of "trait casting".

Comment: See [this idea](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-can-i-cast-self-to-a-trait-object-in-default-method/7993/8?u=adrianheine), though.