# Why must my error be valid for the static lifetime when trying to switch on a concrete error type?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a simple pattern: if I have some error I can try to recover my application, otherwise I just pop this exception to the caller:

```
use std::error::Error;

fn main() {
    let _ = sample();
}

fn sample() -> std::result::Result<i32, std::io::Error> {
    let result: Result<i32, std::io::Error> = Ok(10); // performing some operation
    match result {
        Ok(x) => Ok(x + 1),
        Err(e) => match e.cause() {
            // if it has any error
            Some(cause) => {
                // and it has any cause
                let io_error = cause.downcast_ref::<std::io::Error>(); // and this cause is IO error
                match io_error {
                    Some(_) => Ok(547), // return default value
                    None => Err(e),     // otherwise return an error
                }
            }
            None => Err(e),
        },
    }
}
```

I want to return `x+1` if the operation succeeds. If it doesn't, but it's caused by an `io::Error` then return `547`. If it's caused by something else, just return an error as-is.

The current compiler error is:

```
error[E0597]: `e` does not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:11:25
   |
11 |         Err(e) => match e.cause() { // if it's caused
   |                         ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
21 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
```

I don't understand why it says that it must have the `static` lifetime...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unfortunate, indeed, that the compiler [is not more explicit](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43531).

Let me unwind this:

1. [`Error::downcast_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html#method.downcast_ref) is only implemented for `Error + 'static` (thus, when `self` lifetime itself is `'static`),
2. Thus in `cause.downcast_ref`, `cause` must be `'static`,
3. [`Error::cause`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html#method.cause) ties down the lifetime of its result to that of `self`,
4. Thus in `e.cause()`, `e` must be `'static`,
5. `e` is a temporary introduced in `Err(e)`.

Hopefully, this is clearer.

---

I have not used it yet, however one of the Rust core team members (withoutboats) has been working on a new [`failure` crate](https://github.com/withoutboats/failure) which supposedly solves a number of issue with the `Error` usage.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's a [*requirement of the function you are using*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html#method.downcast_ref):

```
impl Error + 'static {
    pub fn downcast_ref<T: Error + 'static>(&self) -> Option<&T>
}
```

You cannot downcast trait objects that are not `'static`.

The example code can be reduced further to make this more clear. Commenting out the `downcast_ref` allows the code to be compiled:

```
fn example(result: Result<i32, std::io::Error>) -> Result<i32, std::io::Error> {
    let e = result.unwrap_err();
    let cause = e.cause().unwrap();
    let _io_error = cause.downcast_ref::<std::io::Error>();
    unimplemented!()
}
```

---

This may just be an artifact of your reduced example code, but I don't understand why you are taking a `Result<_, std::io::Error>` and checking to see if the cause of the `io::Error` was *another* `io::Error`. If your `Result` was an `Err`, then you know *that* was an `io:Error` as it's the only possible thing. [`io::Error` doesn't even provide a cause](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.22.1/src/libstd/io/error.rs#L546-L552), unless you are using a custom error variant.

See also:

- [Why doesn't Rust support trait object upcasting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28632968/155423)
- [Can I do type introspection with trait objects and then downcast it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27892375/155423)
- [Rust: downcasting and Box<Any>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25246443/155423)
- [How to match trait implementors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26126683/155423)

Comment: I don't understand how it affect this code. `'static` constraint is applied to `T` type which is return type and I really don't care about how long output reference is living. Or it may implicitly applied to `self`...

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy I copied more of of the context of the function — it's implemented on `Error + 'static`.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I'm feeling this diagnostic is missing a note (or a series, thereof) indicating *why* the compiler thinks that `e` should have a `'static` lifetime. It's really not immediately obvious here.

Comment: @MatthieuM. certainly, which is why your breakdown is good. You want to take my reduced example (maybe reduced further) and report an issue with it?

Comment: @Shepmaster: There seems to be multiple issues about this error message already (such as [#43531](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43531)) so I am not sure that it would be very helpful to add more.